# How can I pre-define commands for when I open a new Git Bash command prompt

Tags: git, command-line, git-bash

I have noticed that on my various (Windows 7) machines running Git that when I open a new Git Bash command prompt I can often access previous commands by pressing the up arrow.

These commands differ from machine to machine, but each machine has the same preset commands **every time** I open Git Bash.  One machine for example lets me scroll thorough `git status` and `exit`, another has `exit` and two blanks lines, while a third machine has no previous commands.

Can anyone say how these are set and what I can do to edit them?

Comment: Take a look at `~/.bash_history`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands are stored in the **bash_history** file, which in Windows is `C:\Users\[YOUR USERNAME]\.bash_history\`

Answer (score 1):

To predefine aliases that stick, put things like

```
alias gs="git status"
```

into your `~/.bashrc`.

`~` would be `C:\Users\<username>` in Windows.

Since you were not overly specific with what you wanted:
You seem to want to have a set of commands you can cycle through with <kbd>up</kbd>, based on the commands on all the machines you have used lately. (Which are saved locally in `~/.bash_history` on each machine.)

To just have a common history among all machines without some real dirty hackery is not possible, and also just very unlikely worth the effort. On how to achieve the cycle-through functionality, I have no clue.